# evaluate the line integral, where c is the given curve. messy integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, parametrization

[image]

I used the formula r(t) = r0(1-t) + r1(t) and got t, 2t, 3t for my r(t) vector, and i plugged in the values of x y and z, then plugged them into |r'(t)| and now its one big messy integral and I'm not sure if it was set up correctly, and if it is I'm not sure how to solve it. I have a feeling it shouldn't be this complicated. Even an online integral solver wouldn't solve it. I followed the example in the book and it looked like I was doing it the right way..

Comment: Doesn’t seem like it should be that messy to me. $|r'(t)|$ is a constant, for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^1te^{2t\times 3t}\sqrt{1+4+9}dt$$
$$=\sqrt{14}\int_0^1te^{6t^2}dt$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{14}}{12}\int_{t=0}^{t=1}e^{6t^2}d(6t^2)$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{14}}{12}e^{6t^2}\bigg|_0^1$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{14}}{12}\left(e^6-1\right)$$

Comment: how did you go from the second line to the third line?

Comment: $d(6t^2)=12tdt$

Comment: In other words it's a substitution integral